# I can't get shadows to get into a CG project

Tags: objects

I  am having trouble with getting the shadows to show up on the plane and be in the final image, or I have the shadows and I can't have anything in the background. I have tried moving the plane around the collections. I have deleted the background collection to see if that will work. I have tried both EEVEE and cycles.

This is what ended up being my result.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_PSszoV3_I

What way should I do to get the shadows without that plane?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1COFoLx5YzsNYIfw5tjFddOif4pJAHo6F/view?usp=sharing

Comment: There are some custom python properties assigned to the plane *(Object Properties > Custom Properties)*. Are you using any add-on to set it up? I'd suggest create a new plane and simply render the shadow as separate pass: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RClUL.png

Comment: I got it to work, I changed my render engine to cycles. I went and deleted the background layer and collection. That meant everything was on the foreground and then had this node setup. Movie clip into the top of the alpha over and render layers in the bottom. The fac was one, the premiul was zero. I did not have the checkbox selected. Then that went into the composite node. Then I went to the scene tab and went down to film Selected the plane and then pressed transparent.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. I suggest, add that as an answer and accept it for future visitors... How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour and https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer